# Why can't I get the value of the session？

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

this is my code of app.js, and I save session in mongoDB.

```
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
    const session = require('express-session'); 
    const mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
    const db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/course");
    app.use(cookieParser()); 
    app.use(cookieSession({ //session
       secret: "system",
       store: new mongoStore({
           mongooseConnection: db.connection,
           collection: "sessions"
    })
}))
```

when I want to get req.session.user, I get undefined.
but I save session when user login.

```
    exports.fetchCourse = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("session is: " + req.session.user);
    if(req.session.user) {
        const user = await User.findOne({_id: req.session.user._id}).populate("course");
        console.log("course are: " + user.course.length);
        res.status(200).send({
            code: 1,
            data: user.course,
            msg: "获取全部课程"
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `cookieSession` instead of `expressSsession`.

according to the [docs](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/blob/master/README.md) your code shall look similar to this (if you use express 4 and above):

```
 const session = require('express-session'); 
 const mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
 const db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/course");




app.use(session({
       secret: "system",
       store: new mongoStore({
           mongooseConnection: db.connection,
           collection: "sessions"


 })
```

Comment: yes,but when I use express-session instead of cookieSession, it still don't work.

Comment: I find there are two different sessionIDs. when I send a request,it's sessionID is different with login's sessionID